# Count the number of Scenarios in a particular feature file

Tags: java, cucumber

How to count the total no of Scenarios in a feature file. Like I have a feature file with 5 scenarios. I want to know the total count of scenarios in the @Before function. I basically want to execute certain steps only after the last scenario in a feature file for which I need to know the count of scenarios. Cucumber provides @Before and @After but they are executed after each scenario. I want to execute some steps only after all scenarios are completed

Comment: Try using the `@AfterAll` hook.

Comment: @AfterAll runs after the test run not after every feature file